# Swagger and OAuth2 configuration flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, swagger

I'm working on Spring Boot application which is secured with OAuth2.
I was asked to integrate swagger for documentation. And it was quite easy till the moment i need to configure authorization.
https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-configuration-and-demo-applications

I have read this documentation, but couldn't find any trail which fields should be filled with what.
In my application if i want to authorize i need to do 3 requestes shown on this image.
[Three Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/822HU.png)

I know configuration of swagger is the right place.

```
(...)
      private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("mykey", "api_key", "header");
      }
      private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/anyPath.*"))
            .build();
      }

      List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
            = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return newArrayList(
            new SecurityReference("mykey", authorizationScopes));
      }

      @Bean
      SecurityConfiguration security() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(
            "test-app-client-id",
            "test-app-client-secret",
            "test-app-realm",
            "test-app",
            "apiKey",
            ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, 
            "api_key", 
            "," /*scope separator*/);
      }

      @Bean
      UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return new UiConfiguration(
            "validatorUrl",// url
            "none",       // docExpansion          => none | list
            "alpha",      // apiSorter             => alpha
            "schema",     // defaultModelRendering => schema
            UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS,
            false,        // enableJsonEditor      => true | false
            true,         // showRequestHeaders    => true | false
            60000L);      // requestTimeout => in milliseconds, defaults to null (uses jquery xh timeout)
      }
```

Comment: Hi, have you found any working solution for swagger/springfox?